# Insert or Update in Castle ActiveRecord

Tags: .net, castle-activerecord

Is there a built-in way to do an "insert-or-update" in Castle ActiveRecord?

Something along the lines of:

```
try
{
  ActiveRecordMediator<TEntity>.Create(e);
}
catch (Exception)
{
  ActiveRecordMediator<TEntity>.Update(e);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ActiveRecordMediator<Foo>.Save(foo);
```

Comment: How does it resolve the concurrency problem?

AFAIK: It just work like Insert for new objects and Update for existing attached with DB objects.